# PEM_read_bio_X509 (sometimes) fails (OpenSSL 1.0.1p)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ssl, proxy, openssl

I have created a DSAPI filter to authenticate a user using a client certificate. The user connects via a proxy and the proxy adds the user's certificate to the request header.

```
#define HDR_SSL_CLIENT_CERT                 "SSL_CLIENT_CERT"
```

I am using Apache as a HTTPS proxy; a customer uses NGINX. I have already found that NGINX adds TABS instead of SPACES and I have also made sure that the certificate data has the correct format, before it is parsed by my code

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096
char certData[BUFFER_SIZE+1] = {0,};
```

certData contains the Base64 representation of the certificate ( TABS and SPACES are replaced by \n)

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I then use the following code to get a X509 from certData:

```
    BIO * bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()); 
    X509 * clientCert = X509_new(); 
    bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(certData, -1);
    PEM_read_bio_X509(bio, &clientCert, 0, NULL);

    if (clientCert == NULL) {
        debugOut("PEM_read_bio_X509 failed...\n");

        if(bio) {
            BIO_free(bio);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

We have not seen any issues when using the DSAPI with Apache; also NGINX works. But from time to time, PEM_read_bio_X509 fails and no clientCert is created.

Is there anything obvious wrong with my code?

Is there a known issue with PEM_read_bio_X509 and NGINX?

I am using openSSL 1.0.1p at the moment.

**UPDATE: Here is the code that replaces the TABS and SPACES**

```
char szHeaderAuthToken[MAX_BUF_LEN+1] = {0,};
```

contains the data as submitted by the proxy

```
    size_t last = certLen - lastblank;

    while (szHeaderClientCert[j] != '\0') {
        c = szHeaderClientCert[j];
        // skip first and last 'space' char
        if (j == 10 || j == last) {
            c = ' ';
        } else {
            if (isspace(c) || ('\t' == c) ) c = '\n';
        }
        certData[j] = c;

        if (DEBUGOUT) {
            putchar (c);
            ofs << c;
        }

        j++;
    }

    certData[j+1] = '\0';
```

**UPDATE2: Good and BAD certData**

```
20160512_145926  GOOD

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----


20160512_150227  FAIL

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
20160512_150227 PEM_read_bio_X509 failed...
```

Comment: Just to get an understanding of the problem: the proxy actually verifies the client certificate inside the TLS connection against the expected CA and then adds  the verified certificate to the HTTP request header for further processing. Your (not shown) code extracts this certificate from the request header and then feeds it into your shown code. Have you verified that the extraction is done properly? Can you provide the contents of certData for a case where PEM_read_bio_X509 fails?

Comment: the proxy actually verifies the client certificate inside the TLS connection against the expected CA and then adds the verified certificate to the HTTP request header for further processing

That is correct

Have you verified that .. ?

Yes, the same certificate is parsed without any issue several times before the fail occurs. It is absolutely identical to the one that leads to a fail.

Can you provide the contents of certData ..

There is no difference between the certData that is parsed without issues and the data that ends in an error. This is what drives me mad.

Comment: Actually you are using PEM_read_bio_X509 not like in the examples, see https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/pem.html. In the examples  the clientCert argument should either be NULL or initialized with NULL, i.e. not be an allocated X509_new object. And you should check the return from PEM_read_bio_X509.

Comment: I have tried several variants; all with the same result. 
X509 *clientCert;
clientCert = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio, NULL, 0, NULL);

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the PEM text after the function has run to replace spaces?

This is suspicious:

```
if (j == 10 || j == last) {
    c = ' ';
```

because you are not actually checking if there is a SPACE at that position. You could be overwriting something that is not a SPACE.

And this is suspicious:

```
if (isspace(c) || ('\t' == c) ) c = '\n';
```

because this could easily cause two newlines back-to-back if there happens to be a SPACE before newline, for example.

A SPACE at the end of a line followed by a single newline is OK, but two newlines in a row in the middle of the PEM data would not work and would result in:

```
unable to load certificate
27748:error:0906B06B:PEM routines:PEM_get_EVP_CIPHER_INFO:not proc type:pem_lib.c:446:
```

for example. A simple:

```
$ echo "...your bad cert output from above..." | openssl x509 -noout -text
```

works fine here.

Edit: I've seen NGINX put spaces in front of each line of the PEM -- I don't remember the details. But I would use HTTP_SSL_CLIENT_RAW_CERT with NGINX.

Edit 2: By HTTP_SSL_CLIENT_RAW_CERT, I mean, use $ssl_client_raw_cert from nginx instead of $ssl_client_cert. With $ssl_client_cert you have to remove TAB characters from the start of each line of PEM data.

Comment: >> But I would use HTTP_SSL_CLIENT_RAW_CERT with NGINX.

Could you explain? I cannot find anything about it.

Comment: Look here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_client_certificate -- at the bottom it lists variables. Compare $ssl_client_cert and $ssl_client_raw_cert. I think the HTTP_ is prepended for CGI. Cf. http://blog.honeybadger.io/how-cookies-and-other-http-headers-get-passed-from-nginx-to-rack-and-into-rails/ for into.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the hints and suggestions.

I have rewritten my code; not sure, if this will really solve the issue on the costomer side.

I'm now using boost library to format the PEM data

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim_all.hpp>

std::string cert_data(szHeaderClientCert);
boost::erase_all(cert_data, "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----");
boost::erase_all(cert_data, "-----END CERTIFICATE-----");

if (boost::contains(cert_data, "\t"))
        boost::replace_all(cert_data, "\t", " ");

boost::trim_all(cert_data);
boost::replace_all(cert_data, " ", "\n");

std::vector<std::string> vec;
vec.push_back("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----");
vec.push_back(cert_data);
vec.push_back("-----END CERTIFICATE-----");

std::string szCertData = boost::algorithm::join(vec, "\n");
```

And then get a ( valid) certificate with

```
BIO * bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO_puts(bio, szCertData.c_str());

X509 * clientCert;

clientCert = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio, NULL, 0, NULL);
        if (clientCert == NULL) {
```

...